# Does the Google News Word2Vec model take up storage every time you run it?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

This may seem like an odd question but I'm new to this so thought I'd ask anyway.

I want to use this Google News model over various different files on my laptop. This means I will be running this line over and over again in different Jupyter notebooks:

model=word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin",binary=True)

Does this eat 1) Storage (I've noticed my storage filling up exponentially for no reason) 
2) Less memory than it would otherwise if I close the previous notebook before running the next.

My storage has gone down by 50GB in one day and the only thing I have done on this computer is run the Google News model (I didn't do most_similar()). Restarting and closing notebooks hasn't helped and there aren't any big files on the laptop. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just loading a model won't usually use any more disk storage. (An exception: if load or use needs addressable memory beyond your RAM, you may start using virtual memory, which might show up as less disk space depending on your OS. But, with these sorts of models, you want to avoid relying on any virtual memory, as basic `most_similar()` operations cycle through the full model, & will be very slow if they're reading from disk each time.)

Loading the model will use memory, then more when 1st doing `most_similar()`. (That requires unit-normalized vectors, which are calculated the 1st time needed then cached.)

But terminating a notebook should free that memory. (Note that closing a tab may not cleanly terminate a Jupyter notebook. If the notebook is still running at the notebook server, even with no browsers viewing it, it will still use/hold memory.)

Comment: Hi gojomo, thanks for answering. I've just updated the question slightly but basically I lost 50GB in one day and there are no big files on the computer that's doing this and restarting won't fix it. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Lost 50GB of what, according to what measures/tools? What OS? How did you close/restart any notebooks? Where are you looking for large files?

Comment: Hi gojomo sorry for late response. I lost 50GB of HDD space according to storage available in C Drive when you go to my computer. I have Windows 10. I closed notebooks by simply closing out off jupyter. I looked for large files by doing a search of size:gigantic on my C Drive (https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-locate-large-files-on-a-hard-drive-using-windows-7/).

Comment: What do you mean by "closing out off jupyter"? (That may be part of the problem. If you reconnect to the Jupyter server you may see multiple notebooks still running. But a full restart would've fixed that.) If the problem is consumption of virtual mem, it should show in Task Manager. But again, a full system restart would've helped. There may be files that aren't free'd via restart, or can't be found by your large-file search - but such files would not have been created by gensim. So this is more a Windows OS mystery – & maybe caused by something entirely unrelated to your model-handling code.